# Multi-Threading Long Running Timer in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a C# console application that utilizes System.Timers.Timer that runs 24/7. The timer interval is set to 15000 ms. I have a function called OnTimedEvent that is triggered by the timer which calls a web service to process messages.

The API I am connecting to allows you to check the number of messages in the queue, and download 10 at a time. My function gets the message count, processes the messages (read and db insert) then resets the timer interval. If there are greater than 10 messages, the timer value is 3000ms, if 0, then 15000ms. This forces the application to check for new messages every 15 seconds or keep processing 10 every 3 seconds.

One console application is not enough to keep up with the messages in the API queue, so I launch 2 or 3 depending on the workload. Is there a way to combine the work into one application using threading or parallelism on the .NET (C#) platform?

Comment: have you looked into background workers or thread pools instead?

Comment: This is more or less the same as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35966053/993547) which was closed.

Comment: And this is a question that has been asked numerous times. I closed it as duplicate as one of them, but I could have picked a dozen more. Google is much more effective than posting this question here, so I suggest to read some threads that come up there.

Comment: It is similar to my previous question which was placed on hold for being too broad. I edited the original question but it never re-opened so I tried to get more specific with this one.

Comment: I got that. Your edit wasn't substantial enough to make any difference. The question is still quite broad. This one is better, but a duplicate of others.

Comment: I have researched and read several posts and articles but have not settled on a good solution. Was hoping for user input to help steer me in the right direction. The other post doesn't appear to address the 24/7 issue.